# Android API 33 problems after manifest upgrade

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I encountered a problem. Google notified me that I urgently need to raise the target system from Android API 31 to 33, which I did successfully. After that, I started receiving emails from users stating that after the update, the app does not open. It doesn't just crash upon opening, but rather simply doesn't open. When users tap on the app, nothing happens. I have physical devices, including the Galaxy Note 10 and Xiaomi Redmi 7, both of which work fine, and there are no issues on emulators either. Users with devices like Realme 5, Honor 8X, and Xiaomi Note 8 Pro have reached out to me. When it was just Honor and Realme, I suspected an issue with services, but now with Xiaomi, I'm completely puzzled. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: Is there any error log about this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I rolled back to Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2578 and resolved problem

Comment: i'm facing the same issue after upgrading to SDK 33, did you find a solution?

Comment: @batsheva Yes, I solved the problem by trial and error. I downgraded all Nuget packages like map, essentiial, material etc.

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with upgrading to SDK 33 for Android 13
by me, it was a problem with calling to

> Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

this caused an infinite loop in the code of: onResume and onPause
I found out that in Android 13 we no longer need this permission,
but the compiler didn't tell me anything about this.